# Map values into groups for differents variables

Tags: r

I would like to create a function to map values into groups, and for different variables.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e"), 
                 y = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 6, 8, 3), 
                 z = runif(7), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For example with these datas, for the variable x I want to map the values "a", "b" into "label1" and "c" "d" "e" into "label2", and for the variable y map 1, 3 into "code1" and 5, 6, 8 into "code2".

```
groups <- list(x = list(label1 = c("a", "b"), label2 = c("c", "d", "e")), 
                  y = list(code1 = c(1, 3), code2 = c(5, 6, 8)))
```

In this example, I want to map values from 2 variables, but it can be 1, 3, 4, ... so I don't want to create a dataframe lookup for each variable or assign one by one each variable. That's why I use a list (which I find more friendly in a function parameter) and can't use $. + This is to be used inside a function, so I want nothing hard coded.

So actually I created this function :

```
f <- function(x, groups) {

  table <- reshape2::melt(groups)
  table <- split(table, table$L1)

  for (i in seq_along(table)) {
    x[names(table)[i]] <- table[[i]]$L2[match(x[,names(table)[i]], table[[i]]$value)]
  }
  return(x)
}
```

This is my best try to get a "friendly" groups argument, with nested list.

I tried a syntax like the `dplyr::mutate` one e.g. `myFunction(x = list(label1 = c("a", "b"), label2 = c("c", "d", "e")), y = list(code1 = c(1, 3), code2 = c(5, 6, 8)))` which could be very great, but this is only a part of a bigger function with many arguments so I don't think this is possible (at least I didn't succeed).

But I'm sure there is a better way to do this or maybe there is functions that already exist.
Do you have any ideas of improvements ? Thanks !

Comment: You could have a look at the function `mapvalues` from the `plyr` package - works on vectors (character/numeric/factor)

Comment: "an explanation regarding the downvote could be nice"

Comment: just in case it is what your quotes were implying, I'm not the one who downvoted your question. Although I did hesitate because I don't find it clear enough regarding the expectations.

Comment: Downvoter here. I don't like the imposition of weird conditions that have nothing to do with efficiency ("no data.frame lookups!" or "no loops!" or whatever). If you're going to ask a code review question like this (which is off-topic for SO, but I've done it too), you should be open to whatever solution is best. Conditions regarding simplicity of use are fine, but make them clear. You only have one "?" here and it is nowhere near the constraints you're imposing.

Answer (score 6):

You can try with `match`, with data.frames for your correspondences:

```
# define the correspondences
df2 <- data.frame(v1=letters[1:5], v2=paste0("label", c(1,1,2,2,2)), stringsAsFactors=F)
df3 <- data.frame(v1=c(1, 3, 5, 6, 8), v2=paste0("code", c(1,1,2,2,2)), stringsAsFactors=F)

# change your variables
df$x <- df2$v2[match(df$x, df2$v1)]
df$y <- df3$v2[match(df$y, df3$v1)]
```

**EDIT** taking into account the "new" question's constraints, here is what you can do, keeping `df` and `groups` as they are:

```
tochange <- which(colnames(df) %in% names(groups))
df[, tochange] <- sapply(colnames(df)[tochange], 
                         function(x, equ, df){
                               subequ <- stack(equ[[x]])
                               df[, x] <- subequ$ind[match(df[, x],subequ$values)] 
                               return(df[, x])
                         }, equ=groups, df=df)
df
#       x     y         z
#1 label1 code1 0.6022695
#2 label1 code2 0.1366602
#3 label1 code2 0.2848924
#4 label2 code1 0.6427569
#5 label2 code2 0.1546344
#6 label2 code2 0.3201543
#7 label2 code1 0.6388446
```

Comment: an explanation regarding the downvote could be nice and help me learn something (hopefully)...

Comment: Thank for you answer but this is exactly what i'm doing `x[names(table)[i]] <- table[[i]]$L2[match(x[,names(table)[i]], table[[i]]$value)]` and your solution can only be used in an "interactive" way, (assigning one by one each variable...)

Comment: @JulienNavarre I think you should put a more reproducible example with the real constraints. I thought you wouldn't mind a data.frame lookup because you are creating a list lookup anyway. In your question, you did not precise the "not interactive" way. One has to guess it from your attempts...

Comment: This example is reproducible, maybe I didn't precise all the constraints. I don't mind a dataframe lookup, I do mind a dataframe lookup for each variable, as I said in the original question, this should be a function argument. And I didn't precise that I don't want to do the assignment manually for each variable but I thought the loop in my example was explicit enough.

Comment: @JulienNavarre, see my edit. Hope my answer now meets the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that, like @MarkeD's, puts the encodings in new columns:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
mymaps <- lapply(groups, stack)
for (nm in names(mymaps)){
    setkeyv(df,nm)
    df[mymaps[[nm]], paste0(nm,"_new") := ind]
}
```

To overwrite the variables, you can add `df[,(nm):=NULL]` and `setnames(df,paste0(nm,"_new"),nm)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this - make a named lookup list with what you need:

```
groups <- list(a = 'label1', b='label1', c='label2',d='label2',e='label2', 
              '1'='code1', '3' = 'code1', '5' = 'code2','6' = 'code2','7' = 'code2' )
```

Be careful using numbers as names, as it will default to position.

Then you can get your matches by using subsetting:

```
## generate the data frame example:
df <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e"), 
                   y = c(1, 5, 5, 1, 6, 8, 3), 
                   z = runif(7), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$group_x <- groups[df$x]

## using as.character to avoid numbers throwing off the lookup
df$group_y <- groups[as.character(df$y)]
```

Creates:

```
 x y         z group_x group_y
 a 1 0.1684421  label1   code1
 a 5 0.7459545  label1   code2
 b 5 0.5308211  label1   code2
 c 1 0.6637787  label2   code1
 c 6 0.3493355  label2   code2
 d 8 0.8303369  label2   code2
 e 3 0.8727316  label2   code1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
df[,'x'] <- ifelse(df[,'x'] %in% c('a', 'b'), 'label1', 'label2')
df[,'y'] <- ifelse(df[,'y'] %in% c(1,3), 'code1', 'code2')
#        x     y         z
# 1 label1 code1 0.4536355
# 2 label1 code2 0.2827496
# 3 label1 code2 0.8643375
# 4 label2 code1 0.9481302
# 5 label2 code2 0.8662686
# 6 label2 code2 0.4208953
# 7 label2 code1 0.4438536
```

Comment: I would consider an approach using regular expressions to be dangerous in this case since they're looking for exact matches (so perhaps better to use `%in%`)

Comment: I agree. Also OP says that they need the `groups` style list for function applicability, but there are many ways to subset not involving that assignment i.e. the above solution.